# How do I read the time field from the json-rpc calls from bitcoind?

Tags: json-rpc

The JSON-RPC would return the time in this format `"time": 1346289025`. How exactly do I read it? I don't know what  kind of format it is. So what time is `1346289025`?

Answer (score 3):

It's [unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), the number of seconds since January 1, 1970. Your programming language probably has an easy standard way of converting it to a date.

Comment: Depending on the version of `date` your computer has, you can probably convert it with `date -u --date="1970-01-01 +1346289025 sec GMT"`, `date -d @1346289025`, or `date -jf %s 1346289025`.